# Replacing last occurrence of text string in a text file

Tags: excel, vba

Full Disclosure - Not a programmer here ...
I have had some success with code I found on this site to change individual lines in a text file just fine. But I need to only change the last occurrence of a text string in the same text file. The code below appends the file with the correct change, but that's not what I need it to do. I need it to completely change out "G00 Z.5" to "G00 Z7.0". Below is what I have so far ...

```
Sub TestMacro1()
    Dim sBuf As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iFileNum As Integer
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim NewFileName As String
    Dim Pos As Long
    Dim Str As String

    Dim rplStr As String

    'Edit as needed
    sFileName = "Z:\Code-Unedited\TestText.txt"
    NewFileName = "Z:\Code-Edited\TestText.OUT"

    iFileNum = Freefile
    Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

    Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf

    sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf

    Str = sBuf & vbCrLf

    Loop
    Close iFileNum


    sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "T01 01", "T2001")


    rplStr = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(Str), StrReverse("G00 Z.5"), StrReverse("G00 Z7.0"), , 1))


    'Save txt file as

    iFileNum = Freefile
    Open NewFileName For Output As iFileNum

    Print #iFileNum, sTemp
    Print #iFileNum, rplStr

    Close iFileNum
    End Sub
```

Here is the text file before ...

This is my text file

```
N03 T01 01 M06  
G00 Z.5  
G00 Z.5
```

Here is the output after ...

This is my text file

```
N03 T2001 M06  
G00 Z.5  
G00 Z.5  
G00 Z7.0
```

I need the last occurrence of "G00 Z.5" to be changed to "G00 Z7.0", but not append the new file created like it's currently doing. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sOldText As String
    Dim sNewText As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim aAllFindReplace() As String
    Dim sLastFind As String, sLastReplace As String
    Dim aLines() As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim LastFound As Boolean

    sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files,*.txt", , "Select Text File", , False)
    If sFilePath = "False" Then Exit Sub    'Pressed cancel

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sOldText = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sFilePath).ReadAll
    aLines = Split(sOldText, vbCrLf)
    LastFound = False

    'Change as necessary
    ReDim aAllFindReplace(1 To 12, 1 To 2)
    For i = LBound(aAllFindReplace, 1) To UBound(aAllFindReplace, 1)
        aAllFindReplace(i, 1) = "T" & Format(i, "00") & " " & Format(i, "00")   'T01 01; T02 02; etc
        aAllFindReplace(i, 2) = "T2" & Format(i, "000")                         'T2001; T2002; etc
    Next i

    sLastFind = "G00 Z.5"
    sLastReplace = "G00 Z7.0"

    'Loop backwards to ensure last occurrence is found first
    For i = UBound(aLines) To LBound(aLines) Step -1
        sTemp = aLines(i)
        If Len(sTemp) > 0 Then
            'if you have any general replacements that need to happen, replace those here
            'replacements made here will occur for every instance
            For j = LBound(aAllFindReplace, 1) To UBound(aAllFindReplace, 1)
                sTemp = Replace(sTemp, aAllFindReplace(j, 1), aAllFindReplace(j, 2), Compare:=vbTextCompare)
            Next j

            If InStr(1, sTemp, sLastFind, vbTextCompare) > 0 And LastFound = False Then
                'If you have any replacements that should ONLY happen on the last occurrence, replace that here
                'Replacements made here will only happen on the last occurrence
                sTemp = Replace(sTemp, sLastFind, sLastReplace, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
                LastFound = True
            End If
            sNewText = sTemp & vbCrLf & sNewText
        End If
    Next i
    sNewText = Left(sNewText, Len(sNewText) - Len(vbCrLf))  'Remove ending newline

    'Output the file with the replacements in same location as a .OUT file
    With oFSO.CreateTextFile(Replace(sFilePath, ".txt", ".OUT", Compare:=vbTextCompare))
        .WriteLine sNewText
        .Close
    End With

    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Erase aLines

End Sub
```

Comment: @GSamler Yes, how can I help you?

Comment: I added this under "general replacements": because I need these...
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "T01 01", "T2001")
        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "T02 02", "T2002")
        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "T03 03", "T2003")
        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "T04 04", "T2004")
        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "T05 05", "T2005")

But it just opened a window with no filename in it & it didn't do anything.

Comment: I'm also not changing the "last line", my mistake in describing this, I'm trying to change the last occurrence of G00 Z.5

Comment: How does your code know what the pathname is to the file that is being edited?

Comment: @GSamler See updated code.  As for how it knows the pathname, the code prompts you to select a textfile and stores that filepath and filename in variable `sFilePath`

Comment: That worked! There's no way I would have come up with that code with my limited understanding, thank you!  From here, I was wondering if this can be automated to run on all files in a folder, then output the revised files to a different folder, so they don't get mixed up.

Comment: @GSamler yes, that can be done.  That is a fundamentally different question though.  I recommend creating a new question for that issue.  If you found this answer helpful, please consider upvoting it (up arrow) and/or marking it as an accepted answer (checkbox).

Comment: thank you. I clicked on the up arrow twice, but it says "Those with less than 15 reputation is recorded, but do not change the the publicly displayed post score." Thank you for your help!

Comment: I noticed that the code doesn't change my T10 10, T11 11 or T12 12 to T2010, T2011 & T2012.  I didn't specify this at the outset, because I didn't expect there would be a problem with this. This was working on my previous code, with sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "T10 10", "T2010"). Can you advise on how to add these as well? I figured out how to get 01 thru 09.

Comment: Change the `5` in this line `ReDim aAllFindReplace(1 To 5, 1 To 2)` to be the upper bound you're looking for.  You can consider 65000 as a safe maximum, so if you only need it to go to 12 just change the 5 to a 12 and it can handle that no problem.

Comment: I did that before commenting again, here's what I get even after changing that to 12 ...
This is my text file
N03 T2001 M06N04 T2002 M06    
N05 T2003 M06    
N06 T2004 M06    
N07 T2005 M06    
N08 T2006 M06    
N09 T2007 M06    
N10 T2008 M06    
N11 T2009 M06    
N12 T10 10 M06    
N13 T11 11 M06    
N14 T12 12 M06    
G00 Z.5    
G00 Z7.0

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to force a carriage return on my comments

Comment: @GSamler See update.  The problem was the hardcoded `"0" & i` which was causing `10` to become `010` instead of just `10`.  That should now be corrected.  And comments can't have carriage returns unfortunately, only question and answer posts.

Comment: how do I mark your code as "Answered", I wanted to give you credit for your assistance.  Thank you again for your help!!

Comment: @GSamler There should be a checkmark just below the up/down vote score.  Clicking that checkmark will set the chosen answer.

Comment: Thank you, I just checked the arrow. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

```
Str = Replace(Str, "T01 01", "T2001")
Str = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(Str), StrReverse("G00 Z.5"), StrReverse("G00 Z7.0"), , 1))

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open NewFileName For Output As iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, Str
```

Comment: That changes all occurrences of "G00 Z.5" to "G00 Z7.0". I need it to only change the last occurrence. And it appends the file with the extra line.

Comment: @GSamler - are you commenting on my edit or on the code before? I kind of miss the point why you need `Str`, `sTemp` and `rplStr`?

Comment: Thank you. I was commenting on the code, new to this site. I'm using sTemp to change lines of code that have T01 01, T02 02, T03 03, etc  on it. I was trying to use rplStr to change just the last occurrence of "G00 Z.5" to G00 Z7.0".